# Eulers method- velocity and position as a function of time for runner

Tags: python

Acceleration in a given point is given by a=5-0.004364*v^2
I want to store all the values of v and x  and a in lists so that I later can plot them as a function of time. Keep in mind I'm a beginner. This is my code so far:

```
x_val=0
x=[]
x.append(x_val)

v_val=0
v=[]
v.append(v_val)

a_val=5.0
a=[]
a.append(a_val)

h=0.1

while x_val <=100:
    v_val += (a_val*h)
    x_val += (v_val*h)
    a_val=(5-0.004364*(v_val**2)
    a.append(a_val)
    v.append(v_val)
    x.append(x_val)
```

I'm getting a syntax error on "a.append(a_val)": invalid syntax 
What am I doing wrong here? Please help

Comment: Change `a_val=(5-0.004364*(v_val**2)` to `a_val=5-0.004364*(v_val**2)`

Answer (score 1):

There is closed parenthesis missing in the below line

```
`a_val=(5-0.004364*(v_val**2)`
```